# Insert data into two build-in Auto-increment tables SQL-Server using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

This is my Database

[image]

I want to insert data into Bike and Contact simutaneously. Since Bike is dependent to Contact using ContactId, and the both PKs from the two tables is Auto-increment, I likely have to use ScopeIdentity. However, I'm developing a Windows Store app so the are no Sql Connection, WFC is pretty complicated, any other way to get it done?

This is my code so far in `MainCreate Class`

```
    var _scope_identity = (from contact in contacts
                           where contact.ContactId > 1
                           orderby contact.ContactId descending
                           select new { contact.ContactId }).First();
    NewBike.ContactId = _scope_identity.ContactId;
```

I actually use `.First()` to get the latest record from Contact table. And then

```
    MainCreate mc = new MainCreate();
    Binding b = new Binding();

    b.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedValue.NewBike.ContactId");
    b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    b.ElementName = "grid_CreateBike";

if (tb_contactId.Text == null)
        {
            mc.GetScopeIdentity();
            tb_contactId.Text = mc.NewBike.ContactId.ToString();
        }
```

I think it is also a good way but inflexible. How can I implement that when people choose a Row in a Contacts ListView (for instant a contact with ContactId = 10), then click on a Add Bike button, the system will then recognize that a new Bike creating will be having a ContactId = 10?
Any solutions?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The ownerId of the bike is the ContactID.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :)

Comment: Linq is a query (that is what the q stands for) to read the database and can't be used write database.  The insert function to the database just needs to read the active row of the listview and insert the row into the database.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more specific please?

Comment: Queries are reads of he database.  You want to jnsert.

Comment: Your previous question was tagged [tag:linq-to-sql]. Does that still apply?